# How do I add org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 to my JDK

Tags: java, encoding, classpath, codec

I got this error while compiling a program. I have downloaded the codec needed, i just need to know which folder to add it to.

```
package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist
```

I am compiling the program from console.

Answer (score 0):

You should be alright with any location, as long as you add the Apache commons implementation `.jar` to the `java` or `javaw` classpath. Or in any location where one of your active `ClassLoader` instances can find it anyway.

Comment: You could also add it to the `ext` folder of your JRE, but that is considered bad practice, as you may introduce conflicts with other programs that have compiled against another version of the same.